# Can't inject grailsApplication into service

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

I'm having an issue injecting grailsApplication into a service I created in Grails 2.1. I have built a simple test application (hoping I could figure out this issue and then port the fix over to my real application) that consists of a single controller, view, and service.

The controller looks like this:

```
class IncidentController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

    def incidentService

    def index() {
        incidentService.serviceMethod()
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }

    // Other stuff
}
```

My service consists simply of this:

```
class IncidentService {

def grailsApplication

    def serviceMethod() {
        System.out.println("Grails application: " + grailsApplication)
    }
}
```

And I declare the injection of IncidentService in my resources.groovy as follows:

```
beans = {
    incidentService(org.myorg.test.IncidentService)
}
```

Now everything I have read online says that this should work fine and I should be able to access my configs through the grailsApplication in the service. However, grailsApplication is null whenever I try to. If I add a `ConfigObject` to the service and set it by passing `grailsApplication.getConfig()` from the controller, it works fine.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction for figuring out what the problem is here?

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't have to add your IncidentService to resources.groovy.  If that service is under grails-app/services it will be done for you.  Remove that and try it again.  I think that might be your problem.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Thanks for your help Gregg, you're a life saver!

Comment: added that as an answer so you can accept.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have to add your IncidentService to resources.groovy. If that service is under grails-app/services it will be done for you. Remove that and try it again. I think that might be your problem